# Updating hover tooltip based on different data column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code below that aims to include a hover tooltip to each circle. This issue is that when I append the circle, I am returning lat/long data columns. It seems that the tooltip only works with the data column that are currently being loaded in.

I have other data columns (city, state, etc) that I want to show up in the tooltip instead, however I am not sure how to call those into the code.

To summarize, I want to call d.state (a separate column in my dataset) into

```
"div.html(d.lng + "<br>" + d.lat)"




  d3.tsv("data/read_666.txt")
    .row(function(d) {
      return {
        permalink: d.permalink,
        lat: parseFloat(d.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(d.long),
        city: d.city,
        state: d.state,
        created_at: moment(d.created_at,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            };
    })
    .get(function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

      window.site_data = rows;
    });
});



//display the sites using "permalink"
var displaySites = function(data) {
  var sites = svg.selectAll(".site")
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d.permalink;
  });

sites.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "site")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0];
        })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1];
        })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                         .duration(200)
                         .style("opacity", .9);
                 div.html("State" + d.state)
                         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                 })
         .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                         .duration(500)
                         .style("opacity", 0);
         })
        .attr("r", 1)
        .transition().duration(400)
            .attr("r", 7);


sites.exit()
.transition().duration(300)
  .attr("r",0)
  .remove();
 };
```

Comment: How does your data look like, i.e. what's in `data`?

Comment: its a simple .txt file (converted from a .tsv) that has columns for "permalink", "city", "state", "lat", "long".  I added some code that explains how I load the dataset in.

Comment: just got it to work, added the solution to the main post. thanks!

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the original post. Consider writing a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or deleting the question altogether.

Comment: ok fixed the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: 
Had to update d3.tsv() with the right variable, so needed to add "state: d.state", to get it to work. then I can call it back on the tooltip code